# Github: Transferring repo to organization: "<repo_name> has insufficient collaborator seats"?

Tags: github, open-source

I'm trying to transfer a repo to a free organization - I'm getting an error " {repo_name} has insufficient collaborator seats".

All of the collaborators to the current repo haven't yet accepted the invitation to the organization -- is the error signaling that? Or is it something related to the free account?

Comment: Same error here, probably because, as you said, "collaborators to the current repo haven't yet accepted the invitation to the organization". I will try to remove them and check again if it works.

Answer (score 20):

You must first remove from the original repo/add to the organisation any collaborator that isn't in the organisation yet.

I did so and it worked.

Admittedly the error message `[...] has insufficient collaborator seats.` is not clear enough since we had the same question.

Answer (score 15):

You have a collaborator assigned to the repo that is not part of the organization. So you have two choices. Add them to the organization, or remove them from the repo.

Answer (score 3):

Steps:

1. Go to your original repo that you're trying to transfer
2. Go to settings
3. Click on the Collaborators tab from the left pane.
4. Remove any collaborators

[image]

That's it!